# Business Process Model Versus Process Flow Chart

Tags: flowchart, business-process

What are the differences between designing a process using *Business Process Model* OR using *Process Flow Chart* ?

What are the differences between the two, are these two design tools similar?

Answer (score 1):

The Process Flow Chart originated in 1921 and is pretty simple with 5 symbols:

```
Operation: is to change the physical or chemical characteristics of the material.
Inspection: is to check the quality or the quantity of the material.
Move: is transporting the material from one place to another.
Delay: is when material cannot go to the next activity.
Storage: is when the material is kept in a safe location.
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_process_chart

Business Process is very similar, and a little more specific. If you want something very structured, look at Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN).
The BPMN 1.0 standard was established in 2004 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation)
The BPMN 2.0 standard was revised in 2011 (http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/)

I'd recommend grabbing a cheat sheet for the BPMN sybmols and rules. It's my preferred system when mapping a process involving more than one user.

Comment: process flow chart shows timing and count for each category... but bpm has just the flowchart without quantity of time spent etc.. can you elaborate on this. or have I misunderstood. in my company I have to improve business process, and I want to decide on what I should use.. current vs proposed improvement. find bottlenecks, inefficiencies, redundancy, etc. please elaborate on your answer